# VueJS accessing components from instance

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs2

I am looking for a way to access my component's method from my instance

```
<button id="live" class="ui primary button" v-on:click.prevent="live">
    Live Text
</button>
```

which is directly inside my `#app` and to get it to launch a `live` method from inside my component `Live.vue` I've found tons of documentation prior to ver 2.x about `broadcast` and `dispatch`, but after hour of trying to get it working using `$emit` I am not sure what am I doing anymore ..

```
<template>
  <div v-if="loaded">
    Live
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      loading: false,
      loaded: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    load: function (event) {
      console.log('loading..')
      this.loaded = !this.loaded
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    // this.$on('liveClick', function (msg) {
    //   console.log(msg)
    // })
  },
  name: 'Live',
  props: {
    'id': Number,
    'key': String
  }
}
</script>
```

and `init.js` (it's a laravel based structure)

```
window.App = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   methods: {
     live: function (event) {
       this.$emit('liveClick', 'msg')
     }
   }
})
```

I already did a 'workaround' with Vuex, but I don't need to complicate my learning curve just to get this working.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c4s44qgy/1/

Comment: I think I will be able to help you, but can you explain it better? 
<button id="live" class="ui primary button" v-on:click.prevent="live">
    Live ()
</button>
How function can be inside button?

Comment: also, you have to define `loaded` on the begining. You are toogling it but it is not defined. You should define it as false. Also, you should not use `v-if` on root div in template

Comment: I have it defined, just didn't copy pasted my code and wrote it to skip parts of it that are not related to the question. As for what it is supposed to do it is pretty self explanatory. When you click the button it will show the div saying 'Live' on the place I've put the component tags - it is text inside not a function I had pasted some stuff inside the brackets. I will make it more readable asap.

Comment: could you create quick jsfiddle ? I will help you then.

Comment: for me, it looks like you are trying to use single file components without webpack. Please create jsfiddle and I will help you

Comment: It does uses webpack it has Laravel back-end which is part of the structure. I just use Vue for some front-end stuff like that where simple components are inserted, I can't cover the entire structure but basically this is the vue part https://jsfiddle.net/c4s44qgy/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find fixed fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/gr9c6h64/

Basically, when you want to pass data to components from main Vue instance, you have to use props in this component like I made in the fiddle: `props: { loaded: String }` and then pass value from parent using `:loaded='isLoaded'`

I don't think it is exactly what you want to do, but it looks like it is what you are having issue with. Hope it helps!

Comment: The problem is I can't manipulate the component prop from inside the component, because the prop get's overwritten when the component is rendered again. Which is why I was looking for a way to access the component data or methods from outside the component. It is good workaround, but I can't really make it work that way.

Comment: I think you're wrong. check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/gr9c6h64/2/
Just added input with v-model to show you that data is kept. Re-rendering does not throw data away. This is not a workaround, this is how it should be done. Please explain what more you need

Comment: I think I got it, you are right. It would probably do the job. But it will become really messy later (one thing I never considered before going that way) and I will probably still use the Vuex implementation I already did. It's good to know that it can be done with the props.